What abbreviation for knots do pilots in non-English-speaking countries use?
In aviation, we abbreviate knots as kt. According to Wikipedia:

The ISO standard symbol for the knot is kn. The same symbol is preferred by the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE), while kt is also common, especially in aviation, where it is the form recommended by the International Civil Aviation Organization (ICAO).

The ICAO's recommendation is contained in Annex 5 to the Convention on International Civil Aviation, "Units of Measurement to be Used in Air and Ground Operations".
kt is an abbreviation of the English word. The kn ISO/IEEE standard version, when used in other languages, is customarily translated; for example, in French it's nd, short for "nœud".
How do pilots in non-English-speaking countries typically abbreviate knots? I can think of a couple possibilities – are any of these correct, or is it something else entirely?

Do they use kt (the English version) because English is the "default" language of international aviation?
Do they use a language-specific abbreviation with no difference for the aviation context, for example nd in French?
Do they use a language-specific abbreviation specific to the aviation context, similar to the distinction between kn and kt in English? If so, is there a list or resource explaining these, ideally for many languages?

Does the typical usage differ between languages/countries at all? What about between commercial and general aviation pilots? (For example, do French GA pilots use nd but commercial pilots more often use kt?)
Specific examples or evidence of the typical practice would be helpful.

Another point where context is everything. If it's clear that it's a speed, probably no one will interpret kt as kilo (metric) ton.

Where the instruments are marked in English, it's always option 1 - "kt". This holds for any country.
For non-English content, like translated or foreign-language manuals, it can be anything, "kt" or whatever that language uses, "nd", "уз", "節" or even "kn".
ISO "kn" is one of these things like megagrams and gigameters: technically correct, but impractical. Knots and kilometers can be used in the same context, making "kn" and "km" so easily confused as to be dangerous.

I don't think I've ever seen "nd" on an instrument, though. Ones old enough to still be in French are normally in km/h, France being the origin of the metric system, and new ones are of course "kt". The Swedish Viggen and most other older European aircraft also have their ASI marked in km/h. Russian instruments pre-1990 used metric, and newer ones in the SSJ and the MC-21 are all-English with "kt" as the abbreviation.
Thus it's option 4 for non-English cockpits: km/h or a local translation of the term. Switching from metric back to Imperial units only makes sense when you go for unification with English-based training and symbology, so you wouldn't translate anything.

Side note on origins; "France being the origin of the metric system" occurred in later 1790s. Interesting that just before that in 1792, USA went to metric/base-10 money with the mil, cent, dime,  dollar, etc.

I can't believe the French abandoned all reason and sanity just because everybody else did. That's so wrong! ;-)

ICAO recommendations
ICAO is the UN agency for international civil aviation. All State members apply its recommendations in their official aeronautical publications. Normally only SI units should be used, but there are only a few countries (Ex-Soviet block, China and perhaps India) which are actually compliant and use km/h for speed.
Other non-SI units are allowed by ICAO for specific measurements but they are supposed to be temporary. However there is no definite deadline; these non-SI units are therefore the de-facto and permanent standard for almost all countries.
ICAO recommends using knots (kt) for speed and wind speed in Annex 5 to the Chicago Convention:

Abbreviations are invariant, in the French version of the annex, the unit name is nœud, still abbreviated kt:

French official documentation
The French civil aviation agency publishes its French-language documentation with ICAO unit and abbreviation:

1.7.1 Lorsque des procédures sont conçues pour être utilisées en régions montagneuses, il faut tenir compte de l’erreur
altimétrique induite et des problèmes de contrôle que connaît le pilote lorsque des vents de 20 kt ou plus soufflent sur ces
régions. Lorsque ces conditions sont réputées exister, la MFO est majorée d’une valeur pouvant atteindre 100 %.

Source.
The French AIP use knots (noeuds in French, which should be spelled nœuds actually) and kt (sometimes they use a plural: kts, but this is an error):

Tout aéronef à voilure fixe ayant une masse maximale certifiée au décollage supérieure à 5 700 kg ou ayant une capacité maximale de vitesse vraie au niveau de vol de croisière supérieure à 250 nœuds [..]

Unit/abbreviation used by country

is there a list or resource explaining these, ideally for many languages?

The AIP is the official aeronautical documentation for a country. It states which units are used in the country, at section GEN 2.1. E.g. in France:

Unfortunately I've no consolidated list.
Flight education
Flying schools use kt as expected (but I've seen many non standard spellings in GA course material):

Noter qu’une vitesse d’approche finale supérieure de 10 kt à la normale, entraîne une augmentation de la distance d’atterrissage d’environ 100 m.

Manufacturers
Manufacturers are also supposed to use the same speed unit and abbreviation, however there are a few speed indicators using km/h in some cockpits (like there are a few indicators in statute miles in the English world). It's an exception which can be ignored.
Pilots
Official publications must use the standard proposed by ICAO, and pilots, for GA or airliners, with a private or professional license, are not supposed to use anything else for obvious reasons.

Is km/h even an SI unit? Shouldn't it be m/s?

@Michael, km/h is accepted when using the SI (km is a multiple of a SI unit and hour is a non-SI unit accepted for use with the SI units, source).


Specific examples or evidence of the typical practice would be helpful.

The Dutch weather forecast for general aviation (Weerbulletin voor de luchtvaart), issued by the KNMI (Royal Netherlands Meteorological Institute) uses Dutch abbreviations for all units. For wind, this means "kn", short for "knopen"="knots". For altitude, the abbreviation "vt" for "voet"="feet" is used.
